# How to solve problem with sidebar component when it opens or closes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I really have a problem with rendering this dashboard. I already has this code with comoponent in MUI but when i open the sidebar or close it, have visual problem.

This is my AdminDashboard file in typescript.

```
import router, { Router, useRouter } from "next/router";
import { User } from "parse";
import React, { Children, useState } from "react";
import { CssBaseline, Divider, Grid } from '@nextui-org/react';
import { AppBar, Box, Drawer, IconButton, List, ListItemButton, ListItemIcon, ListItemText, Toolbar, Typography, styled } from "@mui/material";
import { ChevronLeft, Logout, MenuBookOutlined, PostAdd, Settings } from "@mui/icons-material";

const AdminDashboard = () => {
 
  const [isSidebarOpen, setIsSidebarOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleSidebarOpen = () => {
    setIsSidebarOpen(true);
  };

  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
``};

  const handleSidebarClose = () => {
    setIsSidebarOpen(false);
  };

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  // const drawerWidth: number = 240;
  interface AppBarProps  {
    open?: boolean;
  }
  
  const TopBar = styled(AppBar, {
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
  })<AppBarProps>(({ theme, open }) => ({
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    ...(open && {
      marginLeft: 240,
      width: `calc(100% - 240px)`,
      transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
      }),
    }),
  }));
  
  const AppDrawer = styled(Drawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
    ({ theme, open }) => ({
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
        position: 'relative',
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        width: '240',
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
          easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeInOut,
          duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
        ...(!open && {
          overflowX: 'hidden',
          transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
          }),
          width: theme.spacing(7),
          [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: theme.spacing(9),
          },
        }),
      },
    }),
  );

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <TopBar position="absolute" open={open}>
              <Toolbar sx={{
                pr: '24px', // keep right padding when drawer closed
                }}>
                <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="open drawer" onClick={toggleDrawer} sx={{
                    marginRight: '36px',
                    ...(open && { display: 'none' }),
                }}>
                  <MenuBookOutlined />
                </IconButton>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                  Kreu
                </Typography>
                <IconButton onClick={async ()=> {
                  await User.logOut(); 
                  router.push('/login')}
                  } color="inherit">
                  <Logout />
                </IconButton>
              </Toolbar>
            </TopBar>
            <AppDrawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
              <Toolbar sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                px: [1],
                }}>
                <IconButton onClick={toggleDrawer}>
                  <ChevronLeft />
                </IconButton>
              </Toolbar>
              <Divider />
              <List component="nav">
                <ListItemButton href='/'>
                  <ListItemIcon>
                    <PostAdd />
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary="Posts" />
                </ListItemButton>
                <ListItemButton href='/konfigurime'>
                  <ListItemIcon>
                    <Settings />
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary="Settings" />
                </ListItemButton>
                <Divider sx={{ my: 1 }} />
                {/* {secondaryListItems} */}
              </List>
            </AppDrawer>
            <Box component="main" sx={{
                backgroundColor: (theme) =>
                theme.palette.mode === 'light'
                    ? theme.palette.grey[100]
                    : theme.palette.grey[900],
                flexGrow: 1,
                height: '100vh',
                overflow: 'auto',
                p: 2
            }}>
              <Toolbar />
            </Box>
          </Box>
  );
};

export default AdminDashboard;
```

Now as you can see when i open the sidebar is illustrated in below photo:
[image]

And when i closed it:
[image]

I hope you can suggest me any tips or solution for this problem.